# How to get usb webcam to work with Ubuntu 20.04 and zoom

Tags: usb, 20.04, webcam

So I have a fairly old usb webcam I had to dig up since buying a new one is proving difficult right now. The webcam is a Logitech Quickcam Sphere MP. After some finicking I can get it to detect in lsusb and /dev/video however Zoom just outputs a green video feed. I  found some info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Webcam_setup#V4L1_support), but it doesn't seem to work with zoom as nothing changes after loading either shared object file.
Does anyone know if it's possible for me to get this webcam to work with my Ubuntu 20.04 installation? If so, what would be the process to do it (or if you could point me to a different page that explains the process that'd be great too).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick search of the product name on my favorite search engine suggests that it has been discontinued so long that it doesn't even work on Windows anymore.  If logitech isn't supporting the product for the overwhelming bulk of the market share, it's probably not supported anywhere

Comment: So I have a dual-installation of windows/ubuntu and it works on Windows 10 fine. Also I updated my post, as I actually got it to show up in /dev/video. I pretty much only need it to work for zoom, but I'm still a bit pessimistic there's a way to get it to do so since I imagine support for it was dropped with v4l1 and I don't know if there's a roundabout way to get it to work within v4l2.

Comment: What is the permission/ownership of the camera? `ls -l /dev/video`. Is your userid a member of the `video` group? `id`. To join the `video` group, `sudo adduser $USER $(stat --format="%G" /dev/video)`, then logout/in. Check `id` again.

Comment: The permissions are `crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81` and my userid is a member of the `video` group.